# Code Generation Template for C#

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, code-generation, t4

I am looking for a predefined T4 which can generate cod from UML diagrams in C#. I don't want to write code for this template from my hand just want a free template to generate code.

Any kind of help will be valuable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a lot of examples [in this blog](http://www.olegsych.com/)

and there is a [toolkit](http://t4toolbox.codeplex.com/) here.